# Strange window on desktop labeled IPNServiceForm

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Starting yesterday, I've had this little window pop-up on my desktop. It won't go away until I click on it and then just pops-up again. I looked at Task Manager, and I don't see any processes that might be associated with it. I've run a scan, and it's not malware, and searching Google returns no results (which I find incredible). Has anyone else seen this before and can shed some light on it? I am running Win7 x64.

[image: IPNServiceForm]

Comment: Apparently, I didn't look at my Task Manager closely enough. It's part of RedGate software's suite of tools.

Answer (score 1):

a quick search on google for me would suggest IPN is Instant Payment Notification from PayPal (https://www.paypal.com/ipn).

I would be concerned why anything would be using IPN without your knowledge - what have you run a scan with? I would suggest trying a full scan with avast (anti-virus) and spybot (anti-malware) as a matter of precaution.

In task manager look at the processes tab rather than the applications tab and tick show processes from all users, this will list everything that's currently running, if something looks suspicious, google it.